# AS3/Flash: Implement same formula to different variables

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date

In several different moments, I need to convert dates from dd/mm/yyyy to mm/dd/yyyy.

I get the data formated like dd/mm/yyyy from a database.

So, I'd like to know how to use the same formula from different functions. For example in a function I do this:

```
function getMDY (){
    var month = theDay.substr(3,2);
    var day = theDay.substr(0,2);
    var year = theDay.substr(6,4);
    var theDate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    trace (theDate);
}
```

I want to call this function from other functions giving theDay value, and receiving back the value of theDate.

I don't know how to do this. Any clue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getMDY()` needs an input argument and a return value:

```
function getMDY(inputDate:String):String
{
    var n:Array = inputDate.split('/');
    return [n[1],n[0],n[2]].join('/');
}
```

Usage:

```
trace( getMDY("30/08/1991") ); // 08/30/1991
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to define the type of value? (String) I mean, is it possible to recognize the type inside the function and treat the variable based in it's type? Say "case of Number"..., "case of String"...

Comment: @Sergio It's not mandatory unless you're in strict mode, but it's a habit that you should really get into either way. It makes your code far more readable and less bug prone. You can specify an expected value of any type using the `*` wildcard e.g. `inputDate:*`.

Comment: Marty, I know you are right. I was thinking in a function that must deal with different types of values. Thanks for the willcard tip.